# excel vba find first position of unique value, copy values from row below and paste in row above

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked all over but haven't found an answer yet.  I have a set of data where I need to find a first unique value concatenated in column A and B, then move over to row below, copy information from column C:E, and paste it in row above.  Then repeat for next unique value.

I can probably figure out the copy and paste part, but haven't figured out how to find each unique value and it's position.

Below is the sample of data.  So basically I need to find first AustriaEUR, move to next row, copy to values from column 1,2, and 3, and paste in row above, then move on to Australia, etc.

```
Country     Currency    1       2       3
Austria     EUR         null    null    null
Austria     EUR         8.16    8.39    8.73
Austria     EUR         7.94    8.16    8.5
Austria     EUR         7.26    7.49    7.83
Austria     EUR         6.24    6.47    7.06
Australia   AUD         null    null    null
Australia   AUD         8.37    8.59    8.93
Australia   AUD         8.14    8.37    8.71
Australia   AUD         7.46    7.69    8.03
Australia   AUD         7.35    7.58    7.91
Australia   AUD         6.47    6.53    6.61
Belgium     EUR         null    null    null
Belgium     EUR         8.16    8.39    8.73
Belgium     EUR         7.94    8.16    8.5
Belgium     EUR         7.26    7.49    7.83
Belgium     EUR         6.24    6.47    7.06
Belgium     EUR         4.87    5.1     5.43
Belgium     EUR         4.15    4.37    4.71
Belgium     EUR         3.93    4.15    4.48
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but a solution.

Create a concatenated value of columns A & B, then after taking care of the first row, we move down the rows to find the next unique value. Note - this is only set for 20 rows of data at the moment. You'll need `lastrow` to make this dynamic.

```
Sub Test()

Dim myuniquevalue As String, nextvalue As String

myuniquevalue = Cells(2, 1).Value & Cells(2, 2).Value
Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2, 5)).Value = Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, 5)).Value

For i = 2 To 20
    nextvalue = Cells(i, 1).Value & Cells(i, 2).Value

    If myuniquevalue <> nextvalue Then
        myuniquevalue = nextvalue
        Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 5)).Value = Range(Cells(i + 1, 3), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: That worked wonders, thanks!  I have another issue with the same data now though,  instead of finding first instance of a string, I need to find a last instance of that string, and then continue finding those unique values, then I need to copy data from adjacent columns in the row above, and paste in the row below, continuing in that fashion down the list. In this example I would concatenate columns A,B and C, find last value that matches, and then copy down the data from row above. Sample data attached:

Comment: Country Currency Term (in Months) 5 6 7
Austria EUR 12 11.59 12.75 14.04
Austria EUR 12 11.59 12.75 14.04
Austria EUR 12 7.61 9.34 10.5
Austria EUR 12 7.38 9.23 10.27
Austria EUR 12 null null null
Austria EUR 24 8.3 9.37 10.55
Austria EUR 24 4.91 5.77 6.68
Austria EUR 24 4.8 5.66 6.57
Austria EUR 24 null null null

Comment: If you have a new scenario, it's best to open a new question and explain the issue there :)